# Tag subscriptions and "Watch tag"

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching

Something changed about tags.
For the tags I have no subscription the new feature is like:
[image]

whereas for the tags I have a subscription it is like:
[image]

**Questions**: How to subscribe to a new tag? What is the meaning of "Watch tag"?

Comment: Going out on a conjectural limb here: "watch tag" starts a subscription, which you can then remove/alter with "manage subscription". I can only guess what "ignore tag" does. Gerhard "Wait! Don't Press THAT Button!" Paseman, 2018.09.29.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only partial answer, since I was unable to replicate the behavior you describe. (I do not see the "manage subscriptions" button. Possibly the reason that I do not get this button might be that I have set up a new filter subscription just now - to test what you are describing your question? Or perhaps this works only for tags which have been subscribed *before* favorite tags were changed to tag watching?)

As far as I can tell, the difference between [subscriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/subscription/info) and [tag-watching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-watching/info) is that the former provides you with possibility to get updates about content *via email* and the latter changes the way you interact with the questions having these tags *directly on the site*.

> How to subscribe to a new tag?

You can add a new subscription in the page with [filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters/). You can create new filter (or use some of the already existing ones) and choose whether or not you want to receive emails with new questions from this filter. (And also set up how often you want to receive an email with updates.)

You can see all your subscriptions in [the subscriptions tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=subscriptions) of your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current). (It is also possible to unsubscribe and change settings from this page.)

> What is the meaning of "Watch tag"?

Tag watching is simply a new name for the feature which used to be called favorite tags: ['Favorite Tags' is now 'Tag Watching'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180)

As pointed out in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312180/favorite-tags-is-now-tag-watching/312247#312247), there used to be choice to subscribe/unsubscribe on the tag pop-up before this change. The same thing was mentioned in this recent question: [How to subscribe to tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315135)

Some basic information about tag-watching can be found here: [What do “favorite tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173)

**Subscribing to filters**

If you create a filter, you can choose whether you want to receive notification and set up some basic settings - namely the frequency of the updates:

[image: screenshot of email settings]

After you do this, you will receive an email asking you to confirm the subscription. (Basically to check whether you did not make a typo in the email address and whether the email address does indeed belong to you.)

Comment: I have not received any email from my filters since several days. What about you? Have you heard about a problem?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux I have set up the subscriptions only for a few days to test them - after that I cancelled them. But before I unsubscribed, I have received several emails. First idea that comes to mind - have you tried checking whether your email client does not put them into the spam folder?

Comment: It is not in the spam folder. This happens in the same time that this update of the tag feature (before that I received emails from filters almost every day since several years), perhaps there is a bug.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux In order to test this I have set up a few subscriptions in my account again: https://stackexchange.com/users/267077/martin-sleziak?tab=subscriptions I will be able to confirm tomorrow whether I have received email or not. Have you checked the box "Do you want email updates when new questions arrive in this filter?" in the setting of filter? Have you clicked on the link in the confirmation email you received after this?

Comment: Yes for all your questions.

Comment: Ir seems that it works for the new subscriptions, but no more for the subscription made before the new feature.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux I can confirm that I received email notification for the *filters* where I set up subscriptions. (Not all of them, only those ones that actually had some questions.) As I did not have email notification for tag subscriptions before the recent changes, I cannot check that one. Maybe it would be worth a but report - I have found only this, which is relatively recent, but it is already marked (status-completed): [I stopped receiving tag filter subscription notification emails](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313237).

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux Here is a [short discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7302540#7302540) about the issue. We will see how the SE staff reacts to [the recent comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313237/i-stopped-receiving-tag-filter-subscription-notification-emails#comment1037748_313278).

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux According to the comments under the answer [I linked before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313237/i-stopped-receiving-tag-filter-subscription-notification-emails/313278#313278) the bug should now be fixed. I hope it starts working for you.